# Getting an ExperimentalWarning inconsistently

Tags: node.js

I am working on a simple Node-js CLI tool. Within this tool, one of the first lines imports `package.json` so the CLI tool can grab the current version. I am 99% sure that this line is the cause of the error I am getting:

```
(node:3197) ExperimentalWarning: Importing JSON modules is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
    at emitExperimentalWarning (node:internal/util:225:11)
    at ESMLoader.jsonStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:268:3)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:361:14)
```

This is caused by this line (I assume):

```
import pkg from '../package.json' assert {type:'json'};
```

The weird thing is, I don't get this warning every time. If the warning was caused by the line at the top of my script, you would think that the error would be printed every time the script runs, however I **ONLY** get that error when I am passing multiple arguments via the command line.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
import Logger from "../log.js";
let Log = new Logger();
import pkg from '../package.json' assert {type:'json'};

let man = "[...] ";

let flags = [
    {
        "flag" : "-l",
        "name" : "--level",
        "tag" : "level",
        "expectValue" : true
    },
    {
        "flag" : "-v",
        "name" : "--version",
        "tag" : "version",
        "expectValue": false
    }
]

let pargs = {}      // Contains all arguments once parsed
let toSkip = [0,1]; // Tracks IDs of args to ignore
let data = {};
let message = '';

let argRegex = /-+[A-Za-z]/ // Regex used to match command-line arguments ex. "-l"
let kvRegex = /[A-Za-z0-9]*=[A-Za-z0-9]*/ // Matches key=value pairs

if (process.argv.length === 2) {
    console.log(man)
    process.exit(0)
} else if (process.argv.length === 3) {
    if (process.argv[2] === '-v' || process.argv[2] === '--version') {
        console.log(pkg.version);
        process.exit(0);
    }
    Log.log(process.argv[2]);
    process.exit(0);
} else {
    process.argv.forEach((arg, index) => {
        if (!toSkip.includes(index)) {
            if (argRegex.test(arg)) {
                parseArgument(arg, index);
            } else if (kvRegex.test(arg)) {
                data[arg.split('=')[0]] = arg.split('=')[1];
            } else {
                message = arg;
            }
        }
    });
    Log.log(message, pargs.level, data);
}

function parseArgument(arg, index) {
    flags.forEach(flag => {
        if (arg === flag.name || arg === flag.flag) {
            if (flag.tag === 'version') {
                console.log(pkg.version)
                process.exit(0);
            }
            if (flag.expectValue) {
                // flag expects a value, ensure there are enough arguments
                if (index < process.argv.length - 1) {
                    pargs[flag.tag] = process.argv[index + 1];
                    toSkip.push(index + 1);
                } else {
                    console.log("Not enough parameters.")
                    process.exit(9); //Invalid Argument exit code s
                }
            } else {
                // Flag doesn't expect value, so just store the fact that
                // it was passed
                pargs[flag.tag] = true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The error is only ever printed when argument length isn't 2 or 3, which doesn't make sense to me, shouldn't I get the warning every time the script is run?

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same problem. Only difference is that I am trying to run my code within an AWS Lambda function.

If you are not running it within a serverless service try the following console command

- node --experimental-json-modules index.js

Edit:

you may need to revert to commonjs style 'require' style imports. This seemed to solve my problem within AWS Lambda. Remember to remove "type": "module from package.json before you do this though